# CSS Class Not Being Applied To All Similar Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that has three buttons in three containers. The first button in each container has the same `id`, the second button in each container has the same `id`, and the third button in each container has the same `id`. I have a `Javascript` script that accepts incoming information and changes the color of the text in the buttons accordingly. Unfortunately when the script senses that a change needs to be made and attempts to apply the corresponding CSS, only the buttons in the first container get the CSS applied. I'm really not understanding why every element with the same `id` is not getting the CSS applied to it.

The `Javascript` action:

```
document.getElementById('button_1').className = "buttonActive";
```

The button elements:

```
<button id="button_1" class="button"><span id="button_text_1">Button 1</span></button>
<button id="button_2" class="button"><span id="button_text_2">Button 2</span></button>
<button id="button_3" class="button"><span id="button_text_3">Button 3</span></button>

<button id="button_1" class="button"><span id="button_text_1">Button 1</span></button>
<button id="button_2" class="button"><span id="button_text_2">Button 2</span></button>
<button id="button_3" class="button"><span id="button_text_3">Button 3</span></button>

<button id="button_1" class="button"><span id="button_text_1">Button 1</span></button>
<button id="button_2" class="button"><span id="button_text_2">Button 2</span></button>
<button id="button_3" class="button"><span id="button_text_3">Button 3</span></button>
```

Comment: You should not have more than one element with the same ID.

Comment: There's not enough context here as to what the purpose of each of these buttons is.  It would probably be be better if you were using Event Delegation:  http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because `document.getElementById` is returning the **first** element it finds with the specified `id`.

This is because an ID is assumed to be unique.

Consider using class names instead and select them this way:

```
document.getElementsByClassName( 'text' )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select only one dom element using `getElementById`. you should use class instead of id   in case you want to select multiple  element.

you should not use same id for more than two elements in same document.

Note : I replaced id with class for all buttons same thing you should also apply for span.

modified code:

JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button_1').className = "buttonActive";
```

HTML:

```
<button class="button_1" class="button"><span id="button_text_1">Button 1</span></button>
<button class="button_2" class="button"><span id="button_text_2">Button 2</span></button>
<button class="button_3" class="button"><span id="button_text_3">Button 3</span></button>

<button class="button_1" class="button"><span id="button_text_1">Button 1</span></button>
<button class="button_2" class="button"><span id="button_text_2">Button 2</span></button>
<button class="button_3" class="button"><span id="button_text_3">Button 3</span></button>

<button class="button_1" class="button"><span id="button_text_1">Button 1</span></button>
<button class="button_2" class="button"><span id="button_text_2">Button 2</span></button>
<button class="button_3" class="button"><span id="button_text_3">Button 3</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In DOM, every element must have a unique id.
When you do a "document.getElementById()" on multiple elements having the same id, only the 1st object is returned.

Instead use the "name" attribute with `document.getElementsByName` method.

Sample code:

```
var nameArray = document.getElementsByName("elementName");

for(var i=0; i<nameArray.length; i++){
nameArray[i].className = "myClass";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ids should be unique across the entire page.

Use classes instead if you wish to use the same name across page elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById()
```

is only meant to select one DOMelement. ids should be unique. If you want to group elements you should specify class names.

```
<button class="button_1"> ...
<button class="button_2"> ...
<button class="button_3"> ...

<button class="button_1"> ...
<button class="button_2"> ...
...
```

You select all of the first buttons with:

```
document.getElementByClassName('button_1')
```

You can select all of the buttons with:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')
```

In CSS:

```
/* first buttons */
.button_1 { }

/* all buttons */
button {}
```

your code:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("button_1");
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length(); i++){
    var prev_name = btns[i].className;
    btns[i].className = prev_name + " buttonActive";
}
```